# How to sendmail in gas

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I tried trying to send an email with a phrase formatted in html, bold and italic, but it is not working. But the text does not even appear when the recipient receives it. What is wrong? The code is that:

```
if (expire < 10) { 
    var textoHTML = '<b><i>This text should be formatted in bold and italic</i></b>'; 
    MailApp.sendEmail({ 
        to: dataRange[i][7], 
        subject: dataRange[i][8], 
        htmlbody: textoHTML
    })
}
```

Comment: Please use correct formating for your code

Comment: `<span style="font-weight:bold;font-style:italic">This text is formatted in bold and italic.</span>` You can also use <strong> and <i> as well.

Comment: I was able to solve the following:

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve the following:

```
var message = "<HTML><BODY>" + '<i><font size=1> 
               A finalidade básica da auditoria é realizar exames 
               </font></i></A>.' + "</HTML></BODY>";

MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, "", {htmlBody: message});
```

Comment: You should close `html` tag after `body` tag.